# Include &source= in url of navigation item

Tags: navigation

Before recently installing a May 2016 CU to Sharepoint Server 2013 we were able to add a url in our site navigation such like:

```
/sitename/Lists/All Bookings/NewForm.aspx&source=http://site/sitename/SitePages/Thank you for your request.aspx
```

This used to work in that after the user filled out the form they were redirected to our custom Thank you page.
However now after applying the latest CU (we were very behind before this) when I do that it saves correctly but when using the navigation it always links to only http://site/sitename/_layouts/15/

Is there a way to use &source= in my url in the navigation?

Answer (score 1):

If you do have **Minimal Download Strategy** feature enabled than please deactivate it & try it again.

Comment: Thanks Hardik,
I have deactivated it and tried again, but it is still the same behavior.

Comment: Oh, actually. It does seem to have worked - eventually. It didn't work immediately. I made a couple of additional changes including adding the full url again starting with the https://... and changed the "&" to a "?" . I have reactivated the Minimal Download Strategy and the problem has not returned. So I'm not exactly sure this was the solution.

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked for you... Btw I had tried to help you